# rename folder into sub-folder with PHP

Tags: php, directory, rename

I'm trying to move a folder by renaming it. Both the test1 and test2 folders already exist.

```
rename(
 "test1",
 "test2/xxx1/xxx2"
);
```

The error I get is: *rename(...): No such file or directory*

I assume this is because the directory "xxx1" does not exist.
How can I move the test1 directory anyway?

Answer (score 19):

You might need to create the directory it is going into, e.g.

```
$toName = "test2/xxx1/xxx2";

if (!is_dir(dirname($toName))) {
    mkdir(dirname($toName), 0777, true);
}

rename("test1", $toName);
```

The third parameter to [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) is 'recursive', which means you can create nested directories with one call.

Comment: Won't the rename fail if the directory already exists?
Both "xxx1" and "xxx2" are directories, and the second parameter might as well be "xxx2/"...

Comment: it will fail if the target `$toName` exists, but wouldn't you have had that problem with your original code anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make sure all parent directories exist first, by making them?  [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) - use the recursive parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption was correct, this is because "xxx1" in your example does not exist.

So, before `rename("oldname", "/some/long/nested/path/test2/xxx1/newname")` you have to create directory tree structure: `/some/long/nested/path/test2/xxx1/` but `newname` file (or directory) **must not exist** at the moment of `rename` function call.

To generalize the solution look at the following naive function:

```php
function renameWithNestedMkdir($oldname , $newname)
{
     $targetDir = dirname($newname); // Returns a parent directory's path (operates naively on the input string, and is not aware of the actual filesystem)

    // here $targetDir is "/some/long/nested/path/test2/xxx1"
    if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
        mkdir($targetDir, 0777, true); // third parameter "true" allows the creation of nested directories
    }

    return rename($oldname , $newname);
}

// example call
renameWithNestedMkdir("oldname", "/some/long/nested/path/test2/xxx1/newname");

// another example call
renameWithNestedMkdir("test1", "test2/xxx1/xxx2");
```

I named this implementation "naive" because in real production you should also think about handling some edge cases: what if $newname already exists? What if `/some/long/nested/path/test2/xxx1` already exists but it's a file (not a directory)? Why I put 0777 access rights while mkdir? What if mkdir failed?

Answer (score 0):

I think test2/xxx1 would need to exist, so you'd need to use mkdir before you move it.